# Editar objeto, com objetos relacionados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho um Objeto `Cliente` que relaciona com outros dois objetos.

```
[Table("Cliente")]
public class Cliente
{
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Este campor permite apenas 100 caracteres"), Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; } ...

    public virtual Titulo Titulo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dependentes> Dependentes { get; set;}
}
```

Que relaciona com `Titulo`

```
[Table("Titulo")]
public class Titulo
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Cliente")]
    public Guid TituloId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataExpiracao { get; set; }

    //Relacionamento tabela Cliente
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

E com `Dependentes`

```
[Table("Dependentes")]
public class Dependentes
{
    public Guid DependentesId { get; set; }
    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }

    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Estou tentando fazer a Edição desse objeto, e os que se relacionam com ele, utilizando o seguinte método em meu `controller`. Deixei alguns em comentários, pois foi de algumas formas que tentei.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(Cliente cliente)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
       var cli = await db.Clientes
                                .Include(c => c.Titulo)
                                .Include(d => d.Dependentes)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId);

        // Dependentes Originais
        var denpendentesOriginais = await db.Dependentes.AsNoTracking().Where(ct => ct.Cliente.ClienteId == cli.ClienteId).ToListAsync();
        if (cliente.Dependentes != null)
        {
            // Dependentes Excluídos
            foreach (var dependenteOriginal in denpendentesOriginais)
            {
                if (!cliente.Dependentes.Any(dp => dp.DependentesId == dependenteOriginal.DependentesId))
                {
                    var dependenteExcluido = await db.Dependentes.SingleAsync(dp => dp.DependentesId == dependenteOriginal.DependentesId);
                    db.Dependentes.Remove(dependenteExcluido);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }

            // Dependentes Inseridos ou Alterados
            foreach (var dependente in cliente.Dependentes)
            {
                if (!denpendentesOriginais.Any(dp => dp.DependentesId == dependente.DependentesId))
                {
                    // Dependente não existe ainda. Inserir.
                    dependente.ClienteId = cliente.ClienteId;
                    db.Dependentes.Add(dependente);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Dependente já existe. Marcar como alterado.
                    db.Entry(dependente).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
            ViewBag.PossibleUsuarios = db.Users;
            scope.Complete();
            return View(cliente);
        }
    }
```

Neste trecho de código,

```
else
{
   // Dependente já existe. Marcar como alterado.
   db.Entry(dependente).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

tenho um Erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'VendaDeTitulos.Models.Dependentes' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Não tenho certeza se implementei da forma certa, imagino que não, ou se faltou algo.

Como eu posso fazer esse procedimento?

Existe forma melhor de resolver este problema, que o que estou fazendo?

Answer (score 3):

Este código é inútil e está causando seu erro:

```
    Titulo titulo = await db.Titulos.SingleAsync(t => t.TituloId == cli.ClienteId);
    db.Entry(titulo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Aqui você seleciona `Titulo` do banco, marca ele como alterado e salva. O Entity Framework não percebeu qualquer alteração e o objeto passa a ser observado durante todo o restante da execução.

Também não entendi o que este `if` tem a ver com a lógica de dependentes:

```
if (cliente.Titulo != null) { ... }
```

Essa lógica não está boa:

```
        if (!cliente.Dependentes.Any(ct => ct.ClienteId == dependenteOriginal.ClienteId))
        {
            var dependenteExcluido = db.Dependentes.Single(ct => ct.DependentesId == dependenteOriginal.Cliente.ClienteId);
            db.Dependentes.Remove(dependenteExcluido);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Aqui você não necessariamente está selecionando o dependente pela chave dele, o que pode trazer um outro dependente e excluí-lo indevidamente. O certo seria:

```
        if (!cliente.Dependentes.Any(dp => dp.DependenteId == dependenteOriginal.DependenteId))
        {
            var dependenteExcluido = db.Dependentes.Single(dp => dp.DependenteId == dependenteOriginal.DependenteId);
            db.Dependentes.Remove(dependenteExcluido);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Mesma coisa para o de baixo:

```
    // Dependentes Inseridos ou Alterados
    foreach (var dependente in cliente.Dependentes)
    {
        if (!denpendentesOriginais.Any(dp => dp.DependenteId == dependente.DependenteId))
        {
            // Dependente não existe ainda. Inserir.
            dependente.ClienteId = cliente.ClienteId;
            db.Dependentes.Add(dependente);
        }
        else
        {
                // Dependente já existe. Marcar como alterado.
            db.Entry(dependente).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

---

Remova esta parte também, que está só atrapalhando:

```
var cli = await db.Clientes
                            .Include(c => c.Titulo)
                            .Include(d => d.Dependentes)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId);
```